# How do I craft Greensteel Items in DDO

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons-online

How do I go about crafting a greensteel item in DDO?   Are there any guides?

Answer (score 6):

The DDOwiki has a good explanation of the Green Steel crafting process, which can be found [here](http://ddowiki.com/page/Green_Steel_item_crafting_steps).

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://perfectweb.org/ddo/crafting/base_crafting.php) has a very clear and concise javascript tool to help you build your item.  It will also tell you exactly what ingredients you need to gather, and how to craft the sub-components that you need for the final item

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [wiki](http://ddowiki.com/page/Green_Steel_items) page and [tihocan's shroud loot planner](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~delallea/ddo/shroud/index.php) to be very helpful, but an update to the crafting altars makes the crafting process more transparent and easier.